# Error passing conditions in a delete user method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I created a method to remove the user. The essence of the check is that the user can only delete his account, or the admin can do this. However, when you try to delete your account for the user, the error "You do not have permission for this" pops up

```
def destroy
    if @user.present? && (current_user.id == @user.id || current_user.admin?)
      @user.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: t(:destroy) }
      end
    else
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: t(:permission_error) }
     end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really the way to handle this is by using `before_action` to preface the action (or use Pundit instead of reinventing the wheel) so that you're not duplicating the authorization logic all over the place.

```
# app/errors/authorization_error.rb
class AuthorizationError < StandardError; end
```

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from 'AuthorizationError', with: :deny_access

  private 

  def deny_access
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: t(:permission_error) }
      format.json { head :unauthorized }
    end
  end
end
```

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def destroy
    # much dry - such wow
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: t(:destroy) }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    # Don't worry - this will raise an error if the user is not found
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def authorize_user!
    unless @user == current_user || current_user.admin?
      raise AuthorizationError 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If I had to guess at what the error was in your original code its probably that `@user` was never set in the first place.